Maven Build, Release Deploy with a Gitlab Release
I want to build a simple Maven project which I want create a release with Gitlab CI and the TBC templates.
With the maven template it works like a charm:
# included templates
include:
  # Maven template
  - remote: "https://gitlab.com/to-be-continuous/maven/-/raw/3.11/templates/gitlab-ci-maven.yml"

variables:
    MAVEN_SETTINGS_FILE: $MAVEN_SETTINGS
    GIT_PRIVATE_KEY: $GITLAB_CICD_DEPLOY_PRIVATE_KEY
    MAVEN_DEPENDENCY_CHECK_ARGS: org.owasp:dependency-check-maven:aggregate -DretireJsAnalyzerEnabled=false -DassemblyAnalyzerEnabled=false -Dformats=HTML,JSON,XML -DnvdApiKey=$NVD_API_KEY
    MAVEN_DEPLOY_ENABLED: "true"
    MAVEN_DEPLOY_SNAPSHOT_WITH_SLUG_ENABLED: "true"
    MAVEN_BUILD_ARGS: org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:prepare-agent verify site org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:report
    MAVEN_DEPLOY_ARGS: deploy site:deploy -Dmaven.test.skip=true

The deploy will upload the artifact to our Nexus Maven Repository. Now I want to create a Gitlab Release. As far as I understand this may be possible with the semantic-release template. But in the documentation of the maven template is written:

Note: It is the mvn-release job that will perform the release and so you only need the semantic-release-info job. Set the SEMREL_RELEASE_DISABLED variable as shown below."

What is the way to go? Use semantic release with an added Maven plugin and do the release with semantic release or can I combine the Maven and the Semantic-Release template to get a Gitlab Release?
Further I do not know how to configure the assets for the Gitlab Release with the Semantic-Release template. Can anyone help me?

This looks more like a question for https://devops.stackexchange.com/

I don't think so, as my question is aimed at whether and how I could implement this with to-be-continuous

Are you asking about release entry on gitlab project page? The this is not performed by maven. You need a dedicated release job like:
publish release:
  stage: release
  image: registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/release-cli:latest
  only:
    - tags
  script:
    - echo "Publishing release."
  needs:
    - build
  release:
    tag_name: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
    name: 'Release $CI_COMMIT_TAG'
    description: 'Release $CI_COMMIT_TAG.'
    assets:
      links:
        - name: 'jar'
          url: '$DOWNLOAD_URL'

The DOWNLOAD_URL should point to a desire location, like maven central or local packages.

Yes, I'm asking about the entry on the Gitlab project page. I know the Maven release doesn't do a Gitlab release, but the semantic release plugin @semantic-release/gitlab can do such things. But that would probably mean that instead of TBC maven and TBC semantic-release together, I would have to do everything with the TBC semantic-release with a custom semantic-release config. This could then use a semantic-release plugin for maven (https://github.com/conveyal/maven-semantic-release or https://github.com/terrestris/maven-semantic-release). That was exactly the reason for my question.
